# Why wont my program register input from user

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program in python 3.5 which is basically a calculator that works out if the figs that which are entered by a user come together to  make a valid triangle or not.

However when running the program any floats entered in the console isn't registered.

I am using visual coding studio and also i am a noob at coding so any constructive criticism is much appreciated.

```
print("************************")                                                                                                      
print("** ASSIGNMENT (V 2.6) **")
print("************************")

# User input variables / functions

side_a = float(input("please input the length of the 1st side of the triangle "))                                                      
side_b = float(input("please input the length of the 2nd side of the triangle "))                                                    
base   = float(input("please input the length of the base of the triangle "))                                                            


# Formulas 

perim_halved     = (side_a+side_b+base)/2                                                                                                 
area_of_triangle = ((perim_halved*(perim_halved-side_a)*(perim_halved-side_b)*(perim_halved-base))**(1/2))                                                       
perimeter        = (side_a+side_b+base)                                                                                                    
height           = (area_of_triangle/base)                                                                                                      


# Def Functions                                                                                                                      

def valid_triangle():
    print("******* Your triangle is valid ******** ")                                                                                 
    print("******* Area of triangle  =", area_of_triangle,"*******")                                                                 
    print("******* Perimeter of triangle =", perimeter,"*******")                                                                   
    print("******* Height of triangle = ", height,"*******")                                                                        

def invalid_triangle():
    print("******* Your triangle is not valid *******")                                                                                
    print("******** Goodbye ********")

def scalene():
    print("******* Your triangle is a Scalene triangle *******")                                                                        
def isosceles():
    print("******* Your triangle is an Isosceles triangle *******")                   
def equilateral():
    print("******* Your triangle is an Equilateral triangle *******")
def right_angle():
    print("******* Your triangle is a Right angled triangle *******")
def scalene_right_angle():
    print("******* Your triangle is a scalene and a right angled triangle ********")
def isosceles_right_angle():
    print("******* Your triangle is an Isosceles and a right angled triangle *******")

# If statements 

if side_a + base > side_b and side_a +side_b > base and base + side_b > side_a :                                                 


if side_a == side_b and side_b == base:                                                                                            
    valid_triangle()                                                                                                               
    equilateral()                                                                                                                  


elif side_a == side_b and side_b != base:                                                                                          
    if side_a**2+side_b**2==base**2:                                                                                              
        valid_triangle()                                                                                                           
        isosceles_right_angle()                                                                                                       
    elif side_a**2+side_b**2!=base**2:                                                                 
        valid_triangle()                                                                                                              
        isosceles()                                                                                                                     


elif side_a != side_b or base and side_b != side_a or base and base != side_a or side_b:             
    if side_a**2+side_b**2==base**2:                                                                    
        valid_triangle()                                                                                                           
        scalene_right_angle()                                                                                               
    elif side_a**2+side_b**2!=base**2:                                                                  
        valid_triangle()                                                                                                              
        scalene()                                                                                                                        

# Right angle only

elif side_a**2+side_b**2==base**2:                                                                      
    valid_triangle()                                                                                                       
    right_angle()                                                                                                          

else:
    invalid_triangle()
```

Comment: The "[figs](https://www.google.de/search?q=figs&source=lnms&tbm=isch)"?

Comment: Hi, Sorry i meant floats

Comment: What do you mean by "any floats entered in the console isn't registered.". The input is stored in side_a, side_b, and base. What specifically isn't working?

Comment: the only problem with the program is: there is nothing after the first if !!! put all if statements inside that if or just print something, the program works fine !

Comment: Hi Carcigenicate. When I run the code it asks me to enter a float for side_a. When i enter a float lets say for example 6.5 its meant to ask me for side_b variable but that doesn't happen. Please excuse me if I confused you with the words i used before.

Comment: @TheprogrammingHobo You're hitting enter after typing the input right? The code is fine as far as taking input goes. You're sure you aren't getting any errors?

Comment: @Carcigenicate yep, i am hitting enter but nothing in happening not even any error messages. I suspect there maybe something wrong with the integrated/terminal console. I am using  Don Jayamanne extension in visual studio code

Comment: @TheprogrammingHobo Whenever you suspect something like that, just try a different environment. I have the QPython3 app on my phone that I use to verify code behavior. There are also online interpreters that can be used to test.

Answer (score 0):

You have inappropriate indenting you code - in Python it is important!

Almost all lines after

```
if side_a + base > side_b and side_a +side_b > base and base + side_b > side_a :
```

have to be indented (except the last 2).

So your full corrected code (it works - I tested it) will be:

```
# Tested (and works) in Python 3.5.2

print("************************")                                                                                                      
print("** ASSIGNMENT (V 2.6) **")
print("************************")

# User input variables / functions

side_a = float(input("Please input the length of the 1st side of the triangle: "))                                                      
side_b = float(input("Please input the length of the 2nd side of the triangle: "))                                                    
base   = float(input("Please input the length of the base of the triangle    : "))                                                            


# Formulas 

perim_halved     = (side_a+side_b+base)/2                                                                                                 
area_of_triangle = ((perim_halved*(perim_halved-side_a)*(perim_halved-side_b)*(perim_halved-base))**(1/2))                                                       
perimeter        = (side_a+side_b+base)                                                                                                    
height           = (area_of_triangle/base)                                                                                                      


# Def Functions                                                                                                                      

def valid_triangle():
    print("******* Your triangle is valid ******** ")                                                                                 
    print("******* Area of triangle  =", area_of_triangle,"*******")                                                                 
    print("******* Perimeter of triangle =", perimeter,"*******")                                                                   
    print("******* Height of triangle = ", height,"*******")                                                                        

def invalid_triangle():
    print("******* Your triangle is not valid *******")                                                                                
    print("******** Goodbye ********")

def scalene():
    print("******* Your triangle is a Scalene triangle *******")                                                                        
def isosceles():
    print("******* Your triangle is an Isosceles triangle *******")                   
def equilateral():
    print("******* Your triangle is an Equilateral triangle *******")
def right_angle():
    print("******* Your triangle is a Right angled triangle *******")
def scalene_right_angle():
    print("******* Your triangle is a scalene and a right angled triangle ********")
def isosceles_right_angle():
    print("******* Your triangle is an Isosceles and a right angled triangle *******")

# If statements 

if side_a + base > side_b and side_a +side_b > base and base + side_b > side_a :                                                 


    if side_a == side_b and side_b == base:                                                                                            
        valid_triangle()                                                                                                               
        equilateral()                                                                                                                  


    elif side_a == side_b and side_b != base:                                                                                          
        if side_a**2+side_b**2==base**2:                                                                                              
            valid_triangle()                                                                                                           
            isosceles_right_angle()                                                                                                       
        elif side_a**2+side_b**2!=base**2:                                                                 
            valid_triangle()                                                                                                              
            isosceles()                                                                                                                     


    elif side_a != side_b or base and side_b != side_a or base and base != side_a or side_b:             
        if side_a**2+side_b**2==base**2:                                                                    
            valid_triangle()                                                                                                           
            scalene_right_angle()                                                                                               
        elif side_a**2+side_b**2!=base**2:                                                                  
            valid_triangle()                                                                                                              
            scalene()                                                                                                                        

    # Right angle only

    elif side_a**2+side_b**2==base**2:                                                                      
        valid_triangle()                                                                                                       
        right_angle()                                                                                                          

else:
    invalid_triangle()
```

Comment: As given this would be a syntax error so I'm not actually sure it's the real problem as opposed to a transcription error.

Comment: @Iguananaut - I tested it again and again (with different Python versions) and it worked fine - to be sure I repeated copy / paste of the code in my answer again (and I included the Python version as the 1st line). - *In which line you got a syntax error?*

Comment: The line mentioned in this answer without indentation of the lines following it, is a syntax error. An `if ...:` statement must be followed with an indented line *unless* it's followed by a complete one-line statement on the same line (e.g. `if True: pass`)

Comment: @Iguananaut - In my answer the next line *is* intended -  it was the point of my answer, wasn't it? Did you try the code from *my answer* or from the *OP question*?

Comment: @Iguananaut - Tested again, now I copied the code directly from my answer - and it works fine, no syntax errors. Probably is something bad on your side - and I'm very curios what. Please let me know.

Comment: Sorry @MarianD I was referring to the OP in all this, not you.  The OP's code is what's broken.